# Max Char in TextBox C#?

Tags: winforms, textbox, char

Just wondering how many char can C# Textbox multiline hold?

Comment: @Kim Gräsman: how do you know that this question concerns winforms?

Answer (score 34):

Look at the [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx) property of the `TextBox` - it stores the maximum number of characters the control can take; as per the documentation, it is changeable. Usually the default is big enough, though. (Although I imagine that since you're asing the question, it may not be!)

From the docs, you can see that the maximum value for `MaxLength` is **2147483646**. This is, of course, limited by the memory of the target machine.

Comment: According to the docs, MaxLength is NOT the amount of characters the TextBox can hold; it's the amount of characters that can be entered by the user. Programmatically added characters can go above the MaxLength limit.

Comment: I ran in to this issue today. For some reason, my textboxes were set to a default of 32K, and I was trying to paste in a 54K SQL query to a custom tool. The paste was failing about 2/3 of the way in: the data was simply truncated.

I tried manually editing at the tail end; I could delete text, but not edit or add text until I backed up to the 32K limit.

So if you find that text is being cut off, check the MaxLength property and make sure it's set properly.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers seems to assume WinForms development.

If the case that you are doing ASP.NET development, please be aware that the `MaxLength` property of the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` class is ignored when `TextMode = Multiline`. The reason is simple: the `<textarea>` HTML element does not provide any way to restrict the length of its contents.

You will need to do some client scripting in order to enforce a [max length on a textarea](http://www.google.com/search?q=textarea+maxlength).

Answer (score 3):

for Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform :-

> If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of
>       characters the user can enter is 2147483646 or an amount based on
>       available memory, whichever is smaller.

for Windows Millennium Edition Platform :

> If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of
>   characters the user can enter is 32,766 or an amount based on
>   available memory, whichever is smaller.

for more information see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx)

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the link in the last sentence!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any fixed limit on the size of text you can put in a Windows.Forms.TextBox (specifying C# is irrelevant). I've thrown several megabytes of character data in there at times, and it's worked in a satisfactory manner.

However, there may be practical limit - the control isn't oriented towards handling large amounts of text, so performance goes down as the volume goes up.

Depending on the hardware of your users, this may or may not be an issue.

If you need to provide good editing of multi-megabyte text areas, using a properly designed editing control would be a good idea.

Comment: Any recommendations for "a properly designed editing control" ?

Comment: Sorry, no WinForms recommendations - I've not been working in that space recently. AvalonEdit (http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx) is a good open source one for WPF. There are commercial ones for both platforms.