# Multiline TextBox. Maximum lines allowed

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I suppose there's a limit for the lines alowed in a TextBox with the MultiLine option set to true.

I have a program that every several minutes, checks an email account, but for control purposes i put a TextBox that indicates what's been doing.

My curiosity is, does anyone know how much lines are allowed ? And does throw an exception when reached that line ?

**EDIT** Sorry forgot to mention is in WinForms

**EDIT 2** Perhaps, someone knows of a way to eliminate older lines, will grated appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no limit on the number of lines that a text box can display.

There is, however, a limit on the number of *characters* that the control can hold. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382983/max-char-in-textbox-c) for further details on this topic.

Comment: Then i suppose that, the textbox will continue adding lines. Will it erase the older lines ?

Comment: @Chuck, it won't erase the older lines by itself. It will keep adding new lines until it reaches its character limit (2,147,483,646 characters) or it exhausts the available memory, whichever occurs first.

Comment: You are right but its about Multiline not single line, and with MultiLine MaxLength don't work

Comment: @Waqas, true, `MaxLength` is always considered to be `0` in the multiline case. So, the 2G limit applies if, of course, there's enough memory available to satisfy that.

Comment: @Frédéric What makes me a little worry, is if the program will crash after it reaches it's limit. Since th program is some sort of Demon process, it's in a server, perhaps you know of some way of deleting the older lines

Comment: @Chuck, first, is that really necessary? Do you accumulate lines so fast that memory risks being exhausted during the lifetime of the process?

Comment: @Frédéric Not that fast, well maybe, it checks the account every 7:30 minutes, so there maybe a risk of reaching that limit. Considering that in every check informs the progress in the TextBox

Comment: @Chuck, do the math: consider you're adding 1K characters every 7.5 minutes. If your program runs for *a whole year* without interruption, it will consume roughly 70 megabytes of memory, which is... not that much, really :)

Comment: @Frédéric Wow, didn't see it that way, thanks men. Now i can leave my worries behind

Answer (score 3):

If you set the `TextBox.MaxLength` property to zero, the amount of text is limited only by available memory.

Comment: The MaxLength property has no effect in case of multiline

Comment: MaxLength affects the textbox regardless of whether it is single- or multiline, at least in WinForms.

Comment: it affects; **you can say its a bug** but I guess its design issue.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying man, it's a property of the control that can be useful in some cases. If you don't like it affecting multiline controls then set it to zero or something.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" 
MaxLines="6"
TextWrapping="Wrap"  AcceptsReturn="True"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
TextChanged="txtAddress_TextChanged"
PreviewTextInput="txtAddress_PreviewTextInput"
PreviewKeyDown="txtAddress_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

//...

```
private void txtAddress_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
TextBox txtBx = sender as TextBox;
if (txtBx.LineCount > txtBx.MaxLines)
txtAddress.Text = this._textBeforInput;
}

private string _textBeforInput = string.Empty;
private void txtAddress_PreviewTextInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this._textBeforInput = txtAddress.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such limitation on Multiline TextBox both in WinForms and ASP.NET. (I have no idea of WPF :) )

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old and has already been answered, but for those searching for an HTML/ASP.NET solution I have created a short jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z3rdZ/2/

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="limited-lines" maxlines="4"></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#limited-lines').keydown(function(event){
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        var numberOfLines = $(this).val().split('\n').length;
        if(numberOfLines >= $(this).attr('maxlines')){
            event.preventDefault();   
        }
    }
});
```