# Remove Character Limit From Powershell Form Text Box

Tags: .net, powershell

This is a little more difficult to parse and doesn't quite answer my question directly. [TextBox maximum amount of characters (it's not MaxLength)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011508/textbox-maximum-amount-of-characters-its-not-maxlength)

I've got a Powershell form (looks kinda dopey right now) that accepts strings and outputs them to a .txt file.

Run the file, input the text, it outputs a file the way I'd like it to. Only trouble is, large chunks of text (let's say as many as 30 pages) get cut off after a certain character limit. How can I remove limits from the text fields so that any number of characters may be input?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'PCIP'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,500)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'


$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(710,785)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(785,785)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Please enter the author affiliations.'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,50) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
$form.Topmost = $true

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,160)
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label2.Text = 'Please enter the section headings.'
$form.Controls.Add($label2)

$objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox2.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,190) 
$objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox2.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox2)

$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,300)
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label3.Text = 'Please enter the ISBN.'
$form.Controls.Add($label3)

$objTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox3.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,330) 
$objTextBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox3.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox3)

$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,440)
$label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label4.Text = 'Please enter the table of contents.'
$form.Controls.Add($label4)

$objTextBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox4.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,470) 
$objTextBox4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox4.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox4)

$label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,580)
$label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label5.Text = 'Please enter the shortest section.'
$form.Controls.Add($label5)

$objTextBox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox5.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,610) 
$objTextBox5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox5.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox5)

$form.Add_Shown({$objTextBox1.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $affiliations = $objTextBox1.Text
    $sectionHeadings = $objTextBox2.Text
    $ISBN = $objTextBox3.Text
    $TOC = $objTextBox4.Text
    $shortestSection = $objTextBox5.Text
    New-Item -name PCIP.txt -value "<tp>
    $affiliations 
    </tp>
    <sp> 
    $sectionHeadings
    </sp>
    <cp>

        ISBN-13: $ISBN

        Notice and Disclaimer

        The information in this product (`“Product`”) is provided as a reference for use by licensed medical professionals and no others. It does not and should not be construed as
        any form of medical diagnosis or professional medical advice on any matter. Receipt or use of this Product, in whole or in part, does not constitute or create a doctor-patient,
        therapist-patient, or other healthcare professional relationship between the copyright holders and any recipient. This Product may not reflect the most current medical
        developments, and the copyright holders (individually and jointly), make no claims, promises, or guarantees about accuracy, completeness, or adequacy of the information
        contained in or linked to the Product. The Product is not a substitute for or replacement of professional medical judgment. The copyright holders, and their affiliates, authors,
        contributors, partners, and sponsors, individually and jointly, disclaim all liability or responsibility for any injury and/or damage to persons or property in respect to actions
        taken or not taken based on any and all Product information.
        In the cases where drugs or other chemicals are prescribed, readers are advised to check the Product information currently provided by the manufacturer of each drug to be
        administered to verify the recommended dose, the method and duration of administration, and contraindications. It is the responsibility of the treating physician relying on
        experience and knowledge of the patient to determine dosages and the best treatment for the patient.
        To the maximum extent permitted by applicable law, the copyright holders provide the Product AS IS AND WITH ALL FAULTS, AND HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
        AND CONDITIONS, WHETHER EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO, ANY (IF ANY) IMPLIED WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF
        MERCHANTABILITY, OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, OF LACK OF VIRUSES, OR ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS OF RESPONSES, OR RESULTS, AND OF
        LACK OF NEGLIGENCE OR LACK OF WORKMANLIKE EFFORT. ALSO, THERE IS NO WARRANTY OR CONDITION OF TITLE, QUIET ENJOYMENT, QUIET POSSESSION,
        CORRESPONDENCE TO DESCRIPTION OR NON-INFRINGEMENT, WITH REGARD TO THE PRODUCT. THE ENTIRE RISK AS TO THE QUALITY OF OR ARISING OUT OF USE OR
        PERFORMANCE OF THE PRODUCT REMAINS WITH THE READER.
        The respective copyright holders, individually and jointly, disclaim all warranties of any kind if the Product was customized, repackaged or altered in any way by any third party.'
    </cp>

    <toc>
    $TOC
    </toc>

    <ch>
    $shortestSection
    </ch>
    "

}
```

**EDIT, ANSWER**:

It turns out, even though the documentation labels this as belonging to TextBoxBase (and not TextBox, for which the documentation is less complete) the default character limit is, in fact, ~32k, as poster suggests. Simply setting this value with the MaxLength property for TextBox (I set my limit to 200000000) resolves the issue.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'PCIP'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,500)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'


$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(710,785)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(785,785)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Please enter the author affiliations.'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,50) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$objTextBox1.MaxLength = 2000000000
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
$form.Topmost = $true

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,160)
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label2.Text = 'Please enter the section headings.'
$form.Controls.Add($label2)

$objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox2.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,190) 
$objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox2.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$objTextBox2.MaxLength = 2000000000
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox2)

$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,300)
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label3.Text = 'Please enter the ISBN.'
$form.Controls.Add($label3)

$objTextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox3.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,330) 
$objTextBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox3.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$objTextBox3.MaxLength = 2000000000
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox3)

$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,440)
$label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label4.Text = 'Please enter the table of contents.'
$form.Controls.Add($label4)

$objTextBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox4.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,470) 
$objTextBox4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox4.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$objTextBox4.MaxLength = 2000000000
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox4)

$label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,580)
$label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label5.Text = 'Please enter the shortest section.'
$form.Controls.Add($label5)

$objTextBox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox5.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,610) 
$objTextBox5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$objTextBox5.Scrollbars = 3#Scrollbars.Vertical
$objTextBox5.MaxLength = 2000000000
$form.Controls.Add($objTextBox5)

$form.Add_Shown({$objTextBox1.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $affiliations = $objTextBox1.Text
    $sectionHeadings = $objTextBox2.Text
    $ISBN = $objTextBox3.Text
    $TOC = $objTextBox4.Text
    $shortestSection = $objTextBox5.Text
    New-Item -name PCIP.txt -value "<tp>
    $affiliations 
    </tp>
    <sp> 
    $sectionHeadings
    </sp>
    <cp>

        ISBN-13: $ISBN

        Notice and Disclaimer

        The information in this product (`“Product`”) is provided as a reference for use by licensed medical professionals and no others. It does not and should not be construed as
        any form of medical diagnosis or professional medical advice on any matter. Receipt or use of this Product, in whole or in part, does not constitute or create a doctor-patient,
        therapist-patient, or other healthcare professional relationship between the copyright holders and any recipient. This Product may not reflect the most current medical
        developments, and the copyright holders (individually and jointly), make no claims, promises, or guarantees about accuracy, completeness, or adequacy of the information
        contained in or linked to the Product. The Product is not a substitute for or replacement of professional medical judgment. The copyright holders, and their affiliates, authors,
        contributors, partners, and sponsors, individually and jointly, disclaim all liability or responsibility for any injury and/or damage to persons or property in respect to actions
        taken or not taken based on any and all Product information.
        In the cases where drugs or other chemicals are prescribed, readers are advised to check the Product information currently provided by the manufacturer of each drug to be
        administered to verify the recommended dose, the method and duration of administration, and contraindications. It is the responsibility of the treating physician relying on
        experience and knowledge of the patient to determine dosages and the best treatment for the patient.
        To the maximum extent permitted by applicable law, the copyright holders provide the Product AS IS AND WITH ALL FAULTS, AND HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
        AND CONDITIONS, WHETHER EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO, ANY (IF ANY) IMPLIED WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF
        MERCHANTABILITY, OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, OF LACK OF VIRUSES, OR ACCURACY OR COMPLETENESS OF RESPONSES, OR RESULTS, AND OF
        LACK OF NEGLIGENCE OR LACK OF WORKMANLIKE EFFORT. ALSO, THERE IS NO WARRANTY OR CONDITION OF TITLE, QUIET ENJOYMENT, QUIET POSSESSION,
        CORRESPONDENCE TO DESCRIPTION OR NON-INFRINGEMENT, WITH REGARD TO THE PRODUCT. THE ENTIRE RISK AS TO THE QUALITY OF OR ARISING OUT OF USE OR
        PERFORMANCE OF THE PRODUCT REMAINS WITH THE READER.
        The respective copyright holders, individually and jointly, disclaim all warranties of any kind if the Product was customized, repackaged or altered in any way by any third party.'
    </cp>

    <toc>
    $TOC
    </toc>

    <ch>
    $shortestSection
    </ch>
    "

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBox maximum amount of characters (it's not MaxLength)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011508/textbox-maximum-amount-of-characters-its-not-maxlength)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_MaxLength), the `MaxLength` of a `TextBox` defaults to 32767. Setting `MaxLength` to a larger value should fix your problem.

Comment: I was about to answer my own question with this - I just hadn't tested it out quite yet. For some reason, when I first read the documentation, I assumed this wouldn't work because it applied to the TextBoxBase model rather than textbox alone. I also wondered if the default might not be the max as it bases it partially on memory. After trying though, this does work. I'll place my final code in the edits with the proper answer.