# c# - Is there a character limit on textboxes?

Tags: c#, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max Char in TextBox C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382983/max-char-in-textbox-c)

Is there a known character limit in textboxes in c# winform applications with MaxLenght set to 0 ?

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: Why are you asking? Do you have a problem with character limits?

Comment: I actually do not have any issues with this topic but I'm interested if there is a general limit even if I set MaxLength to 0 depending on ram memory size or whatever?

Comment: If you are trying to find out maximums of anything, you are using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Win32 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761647(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> Before EM_SETLIMITTEXT is called, the default limit for the amount of text a user can enter in an edit control is 32,767 characters.
>
> For single-line edit controls, the text limit is [...] 0x7FFFFFFE (2147483646) bytes

[TextBoxBase.MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx) documentation confirms this:

> The number of characters that can be entered into the control. The default is 32767.
>
> If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters the user can enter is 2147483646 [or 32,766 on Windows ME,] or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

for Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform :-

> If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of
>          characters the user can enter is `2147483646` or `an amount based on
>          available memory, whichever is smaller.`

for Windows Millennium Edition Platform :

> If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters the user can enter is `32,766` or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.

for more information see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx)

Comment: @CodeCaster: can you explain , how this value come bcoz of win32

Comment: @RavindraBagale what is `Int32.MaxValue`? Hint: an int is signed, so you lose one bit.

Comment: Mine got downvoted aswell.. sigh. Someone having his fun

Comment: @CodeCaster, No worries dude i didn't realize, i will delete my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
Textbox windows form control:
The number of characters that can be entered into the control.
```

The default is 32767.
    for more details : 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx