# TextBox seems to have a maxlength by default - Cant disable

Tags: c#, textbox

When I try and push the source code from a site such as google into a textbox, the code is truncated after what appears to be a max length or height. I'm not quite sure which one it is yet.

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
          <CheckBox Margin="0,0,30,0" Content="Live Edit" IsChecked="{Binding isLiveEdit, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
          <Button Width="130" Content="Run" Click="Run_Click"/>
          <Button Content="Save Mods" IsEnabled="{Binding siteSaved}"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <ListBox Height="455" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox  Text="{Binding source, Mode=TwoWay}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="600"/>
      </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
```

It appears to not matter if I use TextBox or TextBlock. It hits this invisible limitation. The height of the control is still correct. For example I can keep scrolling but there is no text.

Here is a screenshot of where the textbox appears to end however the listbox that it is in will still allow me to continue to scroll as if it is populated with invisible data.

[image]

Comment: There is a limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526561/c-sharp-is-there-a-character-limit-on-textboxes

Comment: What is odd is that the text exists. I can select text that is CLEARLY not within the textbox and copy it. I can then paste it into another textbox to confirm this.

Comment: A textbox control has it's own scroll viewer, try moving the textbox out of the listbox control.